# bulma - adjusting typography sizing efficiently

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, bulma, sizing

I'm having a hard time figuring out the most efficient way to resize text for mobile. I know per the [documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/typography-helpers/), making the text size responsive to the screen is fairly straightforward, simply add the `is-size-*-mobile` class to an element to reset the text size to the value of `*` (1-7) for mobile devices. What elements are the best place to do this? For example, I would like to be able to have all the text on screen change to size 7 on mobile, but so far I've had to add the `is-size-7-mobile` class to almost every text container on the page. While it's not impossible to do, it seems to be defeating the purpose of having such a class available through CSS.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although they lack a specific example, those **Typography helpers are meant to be added to the element that holds the content you want to modify**.

For example, if you want to modify the whole document consider adding it right to the body element:

```
<body class="is-size-7-mobile layout-documentation page-helpers">
```

The above example works on their documentation page you liked in your question. Just hit F12, add the modifier, and voilà, all the page changes text size.